# Cannot attach to running Flutter app from Android Studio when using flavors

Tags: android, flutter

I'm typically developing Kotlin code for my plugins inside of Android Studio, and debugging while running the example app linked to the plugin. However, I'm having a problem with attaching to the running Flutter app when it uses flavors.

To run it as flutter app I would call

```
flutter run --debug --target lib/main_tst.dart --flavor tst`
```

[image]

When I'm trying to open android folder in Android Studio as native project (not using AS to run Flutter project) and trying to attach to running debug app I see following error.

```
Error running 'Attach debug to process' 
Cannot find AndroidFacet that matches process name com.my.bundle.tst
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to switch to correct build variant in the *Build Variants* panel (in this case for `tst` flavor it was `tstDebug`

[image]